# Create a PCB scheme for circuit

Tags: transistors, capacitor, pcb, circuit-design, proteus

This my first experiment trying to make a PCB circuit.

My main problem is that I want to make a project comping those four simple circuits in one or two pcb's (as I never try to something similar to that ) is it possible to do that and how?

T the schematic captures is ready, but I found the PCB difficult to use protest as every element has many types. For example: if I want a 100 k resistor I have to choose between a loots of kind

I have four circuits that I should print on A4 paper to transmit it to the pcb board.

[image]
[image]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: Yes, there are for example many different types of 100K resistors. And that's why you have to choose the type that you're actually going to use. If you design the PCB for a surface mount resistor, but all you have in your parts drawer is through-hole resistors, you're going to have a big problem when you try to solder everything together. The simplest way is to try it, print it, see if it looks right. If it doesn't look right, go back and change it. Then try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those schematics look like they are all from different sources so you have a long way to go still. The basic steps are:

1) Pick a CAD package. Eagle is very popular in the home/hobby market and so there are lots of tutorials around on how to use it. There are however lots of other choices, don't ask whats best because that a) is opinion based and so off topic and b) depends a lot on what you are doing and what you are used to.

2) Pick specific components. Do you want surface mount or through hole? If surface mount which size, it makes sense to standardize where possible e.g. 0805 or 0603 for all of the Rs and Cs, TSOP or SOIC for ICs. You may want to be a little lazy any check that you are picking parts that you can find libraries for in your CAD package, using your second choice of part/package to avoid having to create library symbols for your first choice is a good idea when first learning the CAD systems.

3) Enter your 4 schematics into the CAD package as a single design specifying the correct parts and packages. Get this wrong and your board will be wrong. Take care that if you want the power or grounds on them to be separate then ensure they have different names.

4) Pass the schematic into the layout part of the CAD system. Make sure you set the board to the correct number of layers (2 is the cheapest) and check that any design rules for minimum spacings are the same or larger than your planned PCB producer requires. You will now have a ratsnest of parts and connections in front of you. Use the CAD package to layout the parts to give the cleanest interconnect possible and then route the traces.

5) When done generate the GERBER files and a drill file, these are the files the PCB house will use to produce the board. You need one gerber file per process layer (e.g. top copper, top soldermask, and top silkscreen and the same for the bottom layer. Inner layers are a single copper layer file). As a sanity check you may want to view these directly. Personally I use a program called GCPrevue to view them and ensure everything is correct but there are other options.

Easy ;-)

Comment: KiCad is another alternative for beginners.  Can't beat the price (it is free.)

Comment: you are the man

Comment: i'll finish every thing and comment here to show you the result

Comment: Getting the board layout "correct" is something that takes time and experience, fortunately for most simple circuits you can be a long way off perfect and it'll still work fine. So if you do post a layout here expect people to find things that they would do different.